# Getting proper UTF-8 from lxml.html.fromstring via requests.get from HTML page?

Tags: python, utf-8

Here is the MWE, `test.py` - the test webpage that is written inline as `mypage`, is served from http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/test/test-utf8.html , so you should be able to run this script as-is:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys
import re
import lxml.html as LH
import requests
if sys.version_info[0]<3: # python 2
  from StringIO import StringIO
else: #python 3
  from io import StringIO


# this page uploaded on: http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/test/test-utf8.html
mypage = """
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <!-- Basic Page Needs
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Page</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
</head>

<body>
  <div>Testing: tøst</div>
</body>

</html>
"""

url_page = "http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/test/test-utf8.html"

confpage = requests.get(url_page)
print(confpage.encoding) # it detects ISO-8859-1, even if the page declares <meta charset="utf-8">?
confpage.encoding = "UTF-8"
print(confpage.encoding) # now it says UTF-8, but...
#print(confpage.content)
if sys.version_info[0]<3: # python 2
  mystr = confpage.content
else: #python 3
  mystr = confpage.content.decode("utf-8")
for line in iter(mystr.splitlines()):
  if 'Testing' in line:
    print(line)
confpagetree = LH.fromstring(confpage.content)
print(confpagetree) # <Element html at 0x7f4b7074eec0>
#print(confpagetree.text_content())
for line in iter(confpagetree.text_content().splitlines()):
  if 'Testing' in line:
    print(line)
```

I'm running this on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS; both Python 2 and 3 give the same results with this script:

```
$ python2 test.py 
ISO-8859-1
UTF-8
  <div>Testing: tøst</div>
<Element html at 0x7fb5b9d12ec0>
  Testing: tÃ¸st

$ python3 test.py 
ISO-8859-1
UTF-8
  <div>Testing: tøst</div>
<Element html at 0x7f272fc53318>
  Testing: tÃ¸st
```

Note how:

- In both cases, `confpage.encoding` detects `ISO-8859-1`, even if the webpage declares `<meta charset="utf-8">`
- In both cases, correct UTF-8 character `ø` is printed from `confpage.content`
- In both cases, corrupt UTF-8 representation `Ã¸` is output from `lxml.html.fromstring(confpage.content).text_content()`

My suspicion is, since the webpage uses `–` UTF-8 character (Char: '–' u: 8211 [0x2013] b: 226,128,147 [0xE2,0x80,0x93] n: EN DASH [General Punctuation]) before it declares `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the `<head>`, this somehow borks `requests` and/or `lxml.html.fromstring().text_content()`, which results with the corrupt representation.

My question is - what can I do, so I get a correct UTF-8 character at the output of `lxml.html.fromstring().text_content()` - hopefully for both Python 2 and 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root problem is that you're using `confpage.content` instead of `confpage.text`.

- `requests.Response.content` gives you the raw bytes (`bytes` in 3.x, `str` in 2.x), as pulled off the wire. It doesn't matter what `encoding` is, because you aren't using it.
- `requests.Response.text` gives you the decoded Unicode (`str` in 3.x, `unicode` in 2.x), based on the `encoding`.

So, setting the `encoding` but then using `content` doesn't do anything. If you just change the rest of your code to use `text` instead of `content` (and get rid of the now-spurious `decode` for Python 3), it will work:

```
mystr = confpage.text
for line in iter(mystr.splitlines()):
  if 'Testing' in line:
    print(line)
confpagetree = LH.fromstring(confpage.text)
print(confpagetree) # <Element html at 0x7f4b7074eec0>
#print(confpagetree.text_content())
for line in iter(confpagetree.text_content().splitlines()):
  if 'Testing' in line:
    print(line)
```

---

If you want to go through the exact problem with each of your examples:

- Your first example is right in Python 3, but not the best way to do it. By calling `decode("utf-8")` on the `content`, since the bytes do happen to be UTF-8, you're decoding them properly. So they will print out properly.
- Your first example is wrong in Python 2. You're just printing the `content`, which is a bunch of UTF-8 bytes. If your console is UTF-8 (as it is on macOS, and might be on Linux), this will happen to work. If your console is something else, like cp1252 or Latin-1 (as it is on Windows, and might be on Linux), this will give you mojibake.
- Your second example is also wrong. By passing bytes to `LH.fromstring`, you're forcing lxml to guess what encoding to use, and it guesses Latin-1, so you get mojibake.

Comment: Fantastic - thanks a ton, @abarnert ; I always get confused with which is which in Python 2 vs 3, so your explanation will be a great resource to refer back to!